# unable to bind onchange event to dynamically added file:input control

Tags: jquery, file-io

I have the following code

```
function testCode(){
 var addControl = '<input type="file" id="fileUploadControl" style="display:none"/>';
    $('#MyDiv').before(addControl);
    $('#fileUploadControl').on('change', 'input:file', function () {
        //My code here for file input control
    });

    document.getElementById("fileUploadControl").click();
}
```

What I am trying to achive here is to add a dynamic input control on the page(that gets clicked when I click one of my custom button)
but I am unable to hit the change event of that control.

can anyone lead me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because of the 'input:file' selector.

Try this instead

```
$('#fileUploadControl').on('change', function () {

 });
```

Comment: Funny thing: i tried this before but it did not worked..but somehow this worked now..